# Are there restrictions on executables compiled with g++ on one Linux distro being used on another?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

Are there any idiosyncrasies or variations between distros that would affect C++ binaries compiled with GCC 4.7.x on one distro being used directly on another? I understand that the ideal situation is to compile from source on the second distro but I'd really prefer not to worry about compiling new GCC versions and the program source code on my production machine. I'm a relatively inexperienced linux user (hence the question!) and still prefer IDEs as opposed to command line compilation, ssh being all I can really use to access the production machine.

The code itself is nothing interesting but it does make use of some run of the mill OS facilities like blocking sockets and the like.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The answer depends very much on if you link statically or dynamically

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem unless one is 64 bit and the other is 32 bit, or if they have significantly different versions of the various shared libraries installed.  If you want maximal portability, you should make it static linked.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: If you want maximum portability you should compile from source.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Static/dynamic linking was definitely an issue I was expecting to see here. Am I right in thinking that the version of the libraries for OS facilities like sockets is tied to the kernel version? Or are they upgraded separately? And also are the libgcc and/or libstdc++ runtime components the only things I have to consider in terms of getting a binary restricted to core C++ running on a different installation?

Comment: There might be incompatible versions of the libraries around (but in that case trying to run the program will complain). More insidious are changes in configuration files location and such.

Comment: @vonbrand: Thanks for the extra food for thought!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the binaries are built on **exactly** the same OS (including version) and **exactly** the same hardware there are no guarantees.

In practice:

1. If the hardware is the same family of chip it should work.

   - This is because most people don't turn on the hardware specific optimizations (but they can).
   - Moving binaries across chip sets is highly unlikely to work
   - Moving binaries from older to newer members of a hardware family is likely to work
   - Moving binaries from newer to older members of a hardware family is less likely (but will depend on optimization and compiler settings (ir moving from 64 to 32 bit architecture is unlikely to work).
2. If the OS has the same Major number then it should (probably) work.

   - The version of OS that a binary will work across will depend on the version of the compiler used to build it and the host OS.
   - If the compiler has changes in the ABI it generates then all bets are off. But usually a change in the ABI generated by the compiler will be a major issue and thus only happen at major points in the OS road map (not at minor increments).
3. My advice build from source.

   - Don't specifically go out and update the development environment (use the one that comes with distribution (if you do the default updates they will not break backwards compatibility)).
   - Building is easy just read the `README` file. But usually it involves running two commands `./configure` and `make`. If you don't want anything special you usually do not need to do anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Much appreciated! The main reason I talk about the latest GCC versions specifically is that I'm very interested in the new C++11 features. I'm comfortable (more or less) with building GCC and some dependencies (MPFR and the other two which I've forgotten the names of) from source but the compilation time/resource usage on a production machine and worry about maintaining another GCC installation feels awkward. What I *don't* know how to do (but want to learn when I have time) is compile my own project from the terminal (heh, I suck!) or use makefiles properly.

Comment: I'd really prefer to try it out first and then think about building from source at a time when I feel more comfortable doing that. The code itself is all pretty high-level stuff, the least portable thing I can find is one or two bitmasks. Based on your answer I've considered the following: both CPUs are x64 from roughly the same vendor family running 64-bit Linux and the distros are the latest versions so, presumably, have a very similar kernel version. And based on that, I've decided it's probably well worth a shot. Thanks again for the sound advice!

Comment: One more thing, if you will: what actually are the factors at play here? As I "understand" (in a loose sense) it, they are: the portability of the generated instructions, the ABI, the versions of runtime libraries involved (presumably trivial if statically linked) and the versions of any OS libraries for things like sockets (which are determined by the kernel version?). But I may well still be barking up the wrong tree! :)

Comment: Current versions of distributions (except for enterprisey, long-life ones which have fallen behind) bundle recent versions of GCC (and clang), so you shouldn't have to compile your own. The C++-2011 support is reported as somewhat spotty, in any case.

Comment: @Elliott, the differences among g++ versions that break binary compatibility are in details of the object implementation, i.e., pretty much everything C++-y.

Answer (score 3):

G++ has had a stable ABI for quite a while, so that shouldn't cause problems. What is likely to cause problems is using dynamically linked libraries. The system running the program will need to have compatible versions of any shared libraries that the executable was compiled against. If you use only static linking, you shouldn't have a problem. You can turn on static linking by using the `-static` option.

Comment: No more true, sadly. G++ 4.7.0 and 4.7.1 had some stdlib changes which affected the ABI, and 4.7.2 had the ABI incompatibilities ["fixed"](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html), which basically means neither 4.7.0 nor 4.7.1 nor 4.7.2 are compatible with any previous version or with any of the other two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks @Damon for the info, very helpful! I've got no qualms about making sure I've got the right runtime libraries etc. but I didn't know what I was looking for until I read that :)

Answer (score 3):

With static linkage, two conditions must be met:

1)    The target system and the build system must be of same architecture (with exceptions: you can run 32-bit binaries on many 64-bit hosts)

2)    The (g)libc package on the target system must not be an older version than on the build system (you can sometimes get away with minor version differences)

It gets more complicated with dynamic linkage.

Comment: also, if I don’t need anything else, can you guarantee that if I compile my code with GCC switch "-march=corei7" it will work on all 64-bit platforms?

Comment: @qdii By the sounds of it, there's no guarantees to be had anywhere here mate!

Answer (score 0):

In general, binaries built on newer distribution does not works on older version, but binaries built on older distribution will work newer distribution. 
For now, if you build binary on RedHat EL4, it would work on most distributions supported.( you may need to copy libstdc++ if missing)